# How can I change element while hovering over another?

Tags: css

I would like to know if it is possible to hover over one element, and change the hover state of another element. The problem is the element I would like to apply the hover state to is higher up in the dom, not below.

Here is my markup…

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  <figcaption>
    <a>View image</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and the CSS I have (which obviously does not work at the moment)…

```
a:hover figure img {opacity:0.3}
```

As you can see I am trying to hover over the A tag and then change the hover state on the image.

Here is a codepen if you wish to test…

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/giEGD

Would love to know if there is a solution.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `figure:hover { opacity: 0.3; }`?

Comment: Yes there is. I do not want the text to change opacity, only the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
figure:hover img { opacity: 0.3; }
```

Comment: Yes this works great. I have also added an inline-block to the figure so it doesn't select the whole block

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're asking for a strictly css solution, but there's always `jQuery.hover()`

[your example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gvkxy) using this

Comment: Thanks but I did want to stick with CSS only, but still good alternative